# How to bind icon and text together?

Tags: html, css

I am using a `<span>` as a container for my icon and text.

```
<span>
    <i class="calendar icon"></i>
    {{ .Date.Format "Jan 2, 2006" }}
</span>
```

The current code allows wrapping of `<i>` and the text separately so I often see both of them present in different lines. Since the icon refers to the text, I'd like to bind both together, somewhat like a `nowrap` alternative. Is it possible?

Comment: What does this do for you ? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<span style=" white-space: nowrap;"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Apr 18, 2018</span>`

Comment: Already tried that, it only applies `nowrap` to the text so the whole text breaks to the new line leaving the icon behind.

Comment: Try this :`<p><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span> Apr 18, 2018</p> `

Comment: @לבנימלכה why would that change the wrapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 

Works
<div style="width:100px"><span style="white-space: nowrap;"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Apr 18, 2018</span></div>
<hr/>
Does not:
<div style="width:100px"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Apr 18, 2018</span></div>
```